# Slider value precise to the second in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a music player with a slider (`songSlider`) that keeps track of the song progress. I.e it moves every second until the song is finished.

**Timer ticks every 300ms**

```
 private void songProgressTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (playlistManager.GetMediaElement().NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
            {
                //Label that shows the currentPosition of song / song max duration
                lblTimeCounter.Content = String.Format("{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}/{1:hh}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}",
                    playlistManager.GetMediaElement().Position, playlistManager.GetMediaElement().NaturalDuration.TimeSpan);
                if (!isSeekingMedia)
                {
                    songSlider.Value = playlistManager.GetMediaElement().Position.TotalSeconds;
                    volumeSlider.Value = playlistManager.GetMediaElement().Volume;
                }
            }
        }
```

**FormattedSlider class method** (fired when slider thumb is moved manually)

```
private void FormatAutoToolTipContent()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AutoToolTipFormat))
            {
                if (AutoToolTipFormat.Contains("%"))
                {
                    var perc = Value;
                    if (Maximum == 1)
                    {
                        perc = Value * 100;
                    }
                    this.AutoToolTip.Content = string.Format(
                        this.AutoToolTipFormat,
                        perc);
                }
                else if (AutoToolTipFormat.Contains("hh") ||
                    AutoToolTipFormat.Contains("mm") || 
                    AutoToolTipFormat.Contains("ss"))
                {
                    var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Value);

                    this.AutoToolTip.Content = string.Format(
                        this.AutoToolTipFormat,
                        timeSpan);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.AutoToolTip.Content = string.Format(
                        this.AutoToolTipFormat,
                        this.AutoToolTip.Content);
                }
            }
        }
```

**When song is played**

```
private void MediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    songProgressTimer.Start();
    TimeSpan ts = playlistManager.GetMediaElement().NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
    double seconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
    songSlider.Maximum = seconds;
}
```

**XAML for songSlider**

```
<framework:FormattedSlider x:Name="songSlider" Width="73" Thumb.DragStarted="SongSlider_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="SongSlider_DragCompleted" ValueChanged="SongSlider_ValueChanged" AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipFormat="{}{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" SmallChange="1"/>
```

**UI of slider**

[image: songSlider]

The tooltip gives you the position of the song, this doesn't change unless you move it and the song gets played at the position of the tooltip on `SongSlider_DragCompleted`.

**The problem**

When I change my slider thumb, even the smallest amount skips ±3-9 seconds instead of 1 second. So there is no way to go to a precise position in the song because the small change isn't 1 second.

I've tried changing smallchange and largechange but it didn't work.
How do I solve this problem so that when the sliderThumb moves manually it will be accurate on 1 second?

*If you need more info/code please let me know.*

Comment: Your question is unclear, and fails to provide a [mcve] that could be used to examine the problem with. One important detail you haven't addressed: if (for example) the song is 200 seconds long, but the slider is only 100 pixels wide, how do you expect that to work? The user cannot move the slider thumb in anything less than whole numbers of pixels (no fractional amounts). You seem to be asking for the impossible. You need to improve the question so that it includes a good [mcve], and clarifies why you think your goal can be achieved.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm sorry that the question is unclear. But you solved it anyways. I indeed was asking something quite impossible. What you mentioned about the pixels is exactly the problem. Thanks for answering.